# How to test google pay push provisioning on qa/sandbox environment

Tags: android, kotlin, google-pay

I am planing the implementation of the push provisioning on the app where I work, but I am struggling to find any documentation that explains how to and how works the tests on qa/sandbox environment for this.
I already found that I can set my google wallet to sandbox, but still I need to configure it a way where it will accept a test OPC, etc.

Tried to find any google documentation about it, but found only the ones here https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android (which I already have access to, but still didnt find anything)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.